# NaN output in Java OOP

Tags: java, oop

I just started learning Java and I'm trying to create a simple BMI calculator using the OOP concept.

Here are my codes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class BIM 
{
    int weight;
    double weightKG = weight * 0.45359237;
    int height;
    double heightMETERS = height * 0.0254;
    double BMI = weightKG / (heightMETERS * heightMETERS);
    public void calculateBMI()
    {    
        System.out.print("The BMI is: " + BMI);
    }
}

public class BMI 
{
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter weight in pounds: ");
        int weight = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("Enter height in inches: ");
        int height = input.nextInt();
        
        BIM b = new BIM();
        b.calculateBMI(); 
    }
    
    private static void bmiCategory (double BMI)
    {
    
        if (BMI < 18.5)
        {
            System.out.println("Underweight");
        }
        else if (BMI < 25.0)
        {
            System.out.println("Normal");
        }
        else if (BMI < 30.0)
        {
            System.out.println("Overweight");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Obese");
        }            
    }
}
```

The output of my codes:

Enter weight in pounds:  100
Enter height in inches: 50
The BMI is: NaN

Why am I getting the output NaN? and also, why is not displaying the category?

Comment: The math happens **once** in your current code. And at the time the math happens, `height` is `0` and `weight` is `0`.

Comment: the weight and height you enter a local to the main-method, height and weight in BIM are 0 and NaN (Not a Number) is the result of division by zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `BIM` class does all the math, but you never pass a `height` or `weight` to it (and you do the math before you assign those values anywhere). First, fix `BIM`. Something like,

```
class BIM {
    public BIM(int weight, int height) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
        this.weightKG = weight * 0.45359237;
        this.heightMETERS = height * 0.0254;
        this.BMI = weightKG / (heightMETERS * heightMETERS);
    }

    int weight;
    double weightKG;
    int height;
    double heightMETERS;
    double BMI;

    public void calculateBMI() {
        System.out.print("The BMI is: " + BMI);
    }
}
```

Then instead of

```
BIM b = new BIM();
```

You need

```
BIM b = new BIM(weight, height);
```

Comment: how do I call the bmiCategory correctly? I called the bmiCategory in main by doing ---> bmiCategory(); OR bmiCategory(double BMI); OR bmiCatetory(BMI); but none of them worked...

Comment: Based on your posted code, `new BMI().bmiCategory(b.BMI);` - it would be a **great** idea to refactor your posted code.

Comment: this works. thank you for your clear explanation. it's been very helpful especially for a beginner like me who only started learning yesterday

Comment: @BellaSwan I've been learning Java for 24 years now. Practice practice practice.

Answer (score 1):

**Mistake 1**
You didn't set the values of the `weight` and `height` attributes, for the object of **BMI class**. You need to add the following code in your **BMI class**:

```java
BIM(int weight, int height){
   this.weight = weight;
   this.height = height;
}
```

and then create an object of **BMI class** as

```
BIM b = new BIM(weight, height);//passing parameters to constructor
```

**Mistake 2**
You didn't call the `bmiCategory` function anywhere, hence the category is not shown.

Comment: not quite right, weight and height are 0.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: double BMI = weightKG / (heightMETERS * heightMETERS);

you are trying to divide weightKG by zero , see below inline comments

**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class BIM 
{
    int weight;
    double weightKG = weight * 0.45359237;
    int height;  // Here value of height is 0 as you are not assigning the value .
    
    double heightMETERS = height * 0.0254; // anything multiplied with 0 height is 0 , heightMETERS value will be 0 
    // The below statement divides weightKG by zero which is infinite and it is not a number 
    double BMI = weightKG / (heightMETERS * heightMETERS); 
    
    public void calculateBMI()
    {    
        System.out.print("The BMI is: " + BMI); // you will sendup printing NaN
    }
}
```

**

problem 2: you are never calling the method bmiCategory to print the catagory based on the BMI.

if I was to reformat and rearrage this code I would do this. We can still improve this with exception handling and so but at the very least we can do this.

**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Bmi {

  public double calculateBMI(double weight, double height) {

    double weightKG = weight * 0.45359237;
    double heightMETERS = height * 0.0254;
    double bmi = weightKG / (heightMETERS * heightMETERS);

    return bmi;
  }

  public String bmiCategory(double bmi) {

    if (bmi < 18.5) {
      return "Underweight";
    }

    if (bmi < 25.0) {
      return "Normal";
    }

    if (bmi < 30.0) {
      return "Overweight";
    }

    return "Obese";

  }


}

public class BmiCalculator {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter weight in pounds: ");
    double weight = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter height in inches: ");
    double height = input.nextDouble();

    //validate inputs
    if(height <=0 || weight <=0) {
      System.out.println("The invalid height or weight, "
          + "height and weight should be a positive non zero inputs");
      return;
    }

    Bmi b = new Bmi();
    double bmi = b.calculateBMI(weight, height);
    String category = b.bmiCategory(bmi);
    System.out.println("You belong to "+category+ " category");

  }


}
```

**

output:

Enter weight in pounds: 100

Enter height in inches: 6

You belong to Obese category

Enter weight in pounds: 0

Enter height in inches: 6

The invalid height or weight, height and weight should be a positive non zero inputs